# Webview not caching all url

Tags: android, webview

I am able to cache `WebView` content of some url's like `google.com` in android.
Only some url's can be cached. While trying to display some url's content offline its showing no connectivity.

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        String weblink = url;

        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
            Log.d("TRIAL","ONLINE");
            browser.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
            browser.loadUrl(weblink);
        } else {
            Log.d("TRIAL","OFFLINE");
            browser.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
            browser.loadUrl(weblink);
        }
}

 private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;
  }  

}
```

Comment: The server can tell the browser not to cache a certain page, and even if a page is cacheable the browser can still decide not to cache it.

Comment: so any way to cache it prgramatically, so that i can load contents offline in webview android.